# Sending Json Object from a php file to a python file?

Tags: php, python, json, zend-framework

I was wondering, is it possible to send a json object encoded in php (zend controller action )file to a python file? Is there any function in python which will decode php encoded json object? If any, please post here your responses.. Thank you

Comment: take a look at python's `json` modul to encode and decode json string

Comment: json.JSONDECODER function is there in oython for decoding the json object..i am just confused that will it serve the purpose of decoding a Json object encoded from a php file..

Comment: As long as the encoder from PHP returns a valid JSON string, any JSON decoder written in any language should be able to correctly parse the one from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RAW String identifier (r) in python. Something like this would work :

```
# Python 2.6.2
>>> import simplejson as json
>>> s = r'{"a":{"a1":"{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"foo1\":\"bar1\"}"}}'
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'a': {u'a1': u'{"foo":"bar","foo1":"bar1"}'}}
```